# django mongoDB boolean field get query has DATABASE ERROR

Tags: django, mongodb, boolean

i am using Donjo for mongoDB for django. and getting error while fetching data from boolean field.
settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                   'ENGINE': 'djongo',
                   'NAME': 'seartzDB'
                 }
             }
```

model.py

```
class DynamicForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250)
    is_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

view.py

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def get_form_view(request):
      email_data = DynamicForm.objects.filter(is_email=True)
      email_list = []
      for i in email_data:
            email_list.append(i.email)
      return Response({'data': email_list}, status=200)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [path('email/get/', get_form_view, name="get_form"),]
```

while i am fetching data from table with boolean field the it gives an error.

```
DatabaseError at /api/v1/blog/comment/create/3/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/v1/blog/comment/create/3/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Location: /home/singham/anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/djongo/cursor.py, line 59, in execute
Python Executable:  /home/singham/anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/media/singham/e1e50bd4-08fa-4ffd-a015-a73c293eaafe/lepy- 
  backup/lokesh/seartz/mongodb/seartz',
  '/home/singham/anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/lib/python38.zip',
  '/home/singham/anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/lib/python3.8',
  '/home/singham/anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  '/home/singham/anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 12 Dec 2020 13:00:40 +0000
```

Comment: can you tell me what django and mongo db version you are using

Comment: and what python version

Comment: python 3.8.5 and django 3.1.4 and MongoDB server version: 3.6.8 and  djongo 1.3.3 for connect mongodb to django

Comment: https://github.com/lokeshsahu01/mongoDB.git   here i have try somthing.

Comment: Brother you haven't called that djongo any where you are calling django.db everywhere but you are using djongo so how it works

Answer (score 1):

For your error please refer docs because all codes have error so please reffer doc's as bellow link
https://medium.com/@9cv9official/django-to-mongodb-djongo-or-mongoengine-d9d56b836a3d
I hope it will helpful for you

```
 DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'NAME': 'blog',
'USER': 'root',
'PASSWORD': '******',
'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
'PORT': 3306,
}
```

Comment: yes you are right, that is the think what i missed. thanks vishal , but in `from djongo.models import forms`
is not exists and after this `from djongo import models` still getting DatabaseError from getting get query by boolean filed

Comment: Wait actually it may be django's problem because most of the time django does not support mongodb if you see django's docs it supports  MySQL,sqlite and PostgreSQL

Comment: But I am trying to find out what problem you are getting

Comment: thanks for your efforts, i also trying to find from my side.

Comment: brother just try this edit it will set sever of database

Comment: yes your correct, but actually i have to use mongoDB only. so i have to do this, so if any solution of this. it will big help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while back but I had found a way to overcome this problem.

```
email_data = DynamicForm.objects.filter(is_email__in = [True])
```

try this one.